# Whats the difference between $ExecutionContext.SessionState.Path.CurrentLocation and $pwd in Powershell?

Tags: shell, powershell, prompt

When I check my prompt function of Powershell, I've noticed `$ExecutionContext.SessionState.Path.CurrentLocation` is used to get current path, so what's the diffence between this and `$pwd`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
PS C:\> $ExecutionContext.SessionState.Path.CurrentLocation

Path
----
C:\

PS C:\> $ExecutionContext.SessionState.Path.CurrentLocation.GetType().FullName
System.Management.Automation.PathInfo
PS C:\> $PWD

Path
----
C:\

PS C:\> $PWD.GetType().FullName
System.Management.Automation.PathInfo
```

So, basically the difference is that `$ExecutionContext.SessionState.Path.CurrentLocation` requires significantly more typing than `$PWD`.

Answer (score 1):

It is true that `$pwd` gets its value from `$ExecutionContext`.

The key difference between these two variables is `$pwd` can be overwritten, but `$ExecutionContext` is Constant (Readonly).

`$ExecutionContext` is intended to mimic the interface available to the cmdlet author. `$pwd` is just a convenient way to get current path.

So, it is recommended to use `$ExecutionContext` if you need to get the path without worrying anyone may messing up the value of `$pwd`.

Comment: IMO, the defensiveness is not worth the loss of legibility. If you really care, try `Resolve-Path .`

Answer (score 0):

`$ExecutionContext.SessionState.Path.CurrentLocation` and `$PWD` actually have difference.

When you use `$PWD` in fact you will get result  of `$ExecutionContext.SessionState.Path.CurrentLocation` ,

whereas if you use `$ExecutionContext` you will get more property about execution context .

Comment: Is that really the answer? Of course, the `ExecutionModel` itself will have more information on it than `SessionState.Path.CurrentLocation`.

Comment: @Christian.K: i mean it's like a tree that have contain many branch of content one of it is $PWD . but not major branch it is in minor branch like sessionstate.path

Comment: Yes, but the OP is asking the difference between to "_branches_": $ExecutionContext.SessionState.Path.CurrentLocation and $PWD.